# Can't Open .cs Files in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

This has been happening pretty consistently for a while now, after changing Solutions a couple of times (across several TFS connections), I run into an issue where I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I try to open any .cs file. I've seen several threads that have similar advice for .cshtml files throwing similar errors, and the solution to that seems to be clearing the Component Model Cache (doesn't work in my case), or running /resetuserdata on devenv.exe (this works, but of the few settings that this does actually delete, it deletes TFS connections (most frustratingly).

I've uninstalled/reinstalled visual studio, uninstalled any plugins I've been using and uninstalled/reinstalled versions of dotnet, and still nothing. Has anyone run into anything like this before? I'm on version 15.7.3, and dotnet framework version 4.7.03056.

If any other clarifying information would be helpful in troubleshooting this, let me know.

Update: I found that I can open the files via the source control explorer when I'm not in the solution they're a part of.

Comment: Next time it happens, try turning off your AV and see if that fixes the problem. You could also try shutting down other services.

Comment: I've tried disabling services, to no real avail. Still happens after I switch into a different solution @polyfun

Comment: You could try using Process Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to see if any other processes are accessing your .cs files when the error happens.